# jQuery UI tooltip open and close repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have a div with the following structure:

```
<div id="notify" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" title=""></a></div>
```

I would like to use the jQuery tooltip UI widget to repeatedly open and close on repeated update of another div using ajax. My code snippet for tooltip is as below

```
jQuery( "#notify a" ).tooltip({
                    show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 },
                    hide: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 }
                });

var tooltipTxt = r[x].name+" is "+r[x].status.toLowerCase();

            jQuery( "#notify a" ).tooltip({content: tooltipTxt});

                jQuery("#notify a").tooltip("open");

                setTimeout(function(){
                    jQuery( "#notify a" ).tooltip("close");

                }, 3000);
```

Here 'r' is a JSON retrieved with AJAX

The problem is that the tooltip opens and closes only once. If this cannot be solved what will be the correct UI widget to use in this situation.

Comment: sorry i missed out on the structure . Its as below    <div id="notify" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" title=""></a></div>

Comment: You can edit your question if you need to clarify it further.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( "#notify a" ).tooltip({
                    show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 },
                    hide: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 }
                });

var tooltipTxt = r[x].name+" is "+r[x].status.toLowerCase();

                jQuery( "#notify a" ).tooltip("enable");
                jQuery( "#notify a" ).attr("title", tooltipTxt);

                jQuery( "#notify a" ).tooltip({ content: tooltipTxt});

                jQuery("#notify a").tooltip("open");

                setTimeout(function(){
                    jQuery( "#notify a" ).tooltip("disable");

                }, 3000);
```

I found the above workaround using 
    .tooltip("enable") and .tooltip("disable") instead of .tooltip("open") and .tooltip("close")

I also set the title attribute of tooltip manually using 
    jQuery( "#notify a" ).attr("title", tooltipTxt);